# Flask: Stream rádio

Tags: html, python, flask, streaming

Esta é a primeira que vou tentar embarcar em projeto desse estilo e estou com algumas dúvidas que gostaria de esclarecer, isso pode soar de forma bem leiga.

Usarei Flask para desenvolvimento e rádio está estabelecida na plataforma `SHOUTcast`, me conecto atrás de um  `IP:PORTA`. Estou começando aos poucos a entender a arquitetura do Flask, já havia feito um pequeno projeto usando ele e gostei bastante.

Agora para criar um audio player, de que forma pode ser feita? Usando Python, HTML? Ainda não consegui compreender a forma de trabalhar com isso.

Pode ser utilizado [Plyr](https://plyr.io/) ?

Comment: Não está claro o que você quer fazer. Quer fazer um servidor de streaming de áudio? Quer fazer um player de áudio web?

Comment: Então, gostaria de transmitir esse broadcast atráves de player, correto? De que maneira eu faço isso

Comment: A Rádio já está hospedada no `SHOUTcast`, recebo um IP:PORTA, agora precisa ter um player na web

Comment: Eu descobri um próprio gerador do `SHOUTcast`.
 https://shoutcastwidgets.com/flash_player_generator.php acredito que isso vai me servir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você já tem o servidor de streaming separado, o que você precisa é fazer chegar no browser uma tag de "`<audio />`" com os parâmetros apropriados - 
essa é a parte que você faz no flask.

A recomendação é você testar com uma página estática antes - aqui tem uma boa documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

quando estiver ok, se for o mesmo link para todos os usuários, você pode deixar a tag estática, ou, se preencher o elemento áudio e endereço do servidor, etc.. no template, com variáveis que são gerenciadas na view em Python.

Se a sua aplicação final for do tipo "web application" - em que você mantém uma única página HTML e vai atualizando a mesma com requisições assíncronas ao servidor - a mesma coisa - efetivamente a view em Python vai passar a URL no servidor, e a parte em Javascript da sua app vai criar a tag de áudio com esses parâmetros.